# Pytest with logging and Click fails with ValueError only within Docker

Tags: python, docker, pytest, python-click

I have a library I'm working on which makes use of Click. It's contained within a Docker image. I'm trying to test it using pytest using `click.testing.CliRunner`. I'm using `logging` to write logs, and I've specified that these logs should be emitted in the `pyproject.toml`. When an exception is raised in my code, and *only within Docker*, I get the following exception from Click:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/testing.py:434: ValueError
            except Exception as e:
                if not catch_exceptions:
                    raise
                exception = e
                exit_code = 1
                exc_info = sys.exc_info()
            finally:
                sys.stdout.flush()
>               stdout = outstreams[0].getvalue()
E               ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/testing.py:434: ValueError
```

I've managed to minimally reproduce this issue. My code looks something like this:

```py
import logging, click

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@click.command()
@click.argument('value')
def main(value):
    logger.info(value)
    raise RuntimeError()
```

My tests look like this:

```py
import pytest
from click.testing import CliRunner

from main import main

def test_main():
    runner = CliRunner()
    runner.invoke(main, ['hello'], catch_exceptions=False)
    assert True
```

And my `pyproject.toml` is:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli = true
log_level = "INFO"
```

Removing the logging, the `CliRunner`, or pytest (i.e. running `test_main` directly) does not trigger the `ValueError`, and the `RuntimeError` is the only exception raised. Running this outside of a Docker container also does not raise the `ValueError`.

How can I avoid this error?

This code is available on [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/MatthewJA/click-pytest-logger) for reproduction. I reproduced this issue in a `continuum/miniconda3` container.

Comment: There seems to be an outstanding issue/bug between pytest and the click CliRunner, [ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in testing · Issue #824 · pallets/click](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/824). 
This issue has been open since 2017. I have not found a solution. The only workaround seems to be to not set log_cli to True or to avoid using CliRunner., neither of which I really want to do. Did you find a suitable workaround?